# iterating a list and creating new list with name of field in iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have done some reading and from what I gather dynamically creating objects isn't a good idea. My question is how do I go about solving my dilemma If I shouldn't dynamically generate object names.

I'm creating a new user script that will pull details out of a system and create a csv with the relevant information to be imported into Active Directory. This part is done and working well, However the next step to automate the process of creating users is to email the tutors a list of their students details so they can give this out when they see their tutor group.

to give some background the information im putting into the csv is as follows

```
stu = (
    row['LearnerCode'],
    PersonPin[0],        
    row['Forename'].replace("'", '').replace(' ', '').replace('-',''),
    row['Surname'].replace("'", '').replace(' ', '').replace('-',''),
    row['RegGroup'],
    row['Year'],
    row['DateOfEntry'],
    Email,
    UserName,
    OUYear,
    )
```

This is inside of a for loop, so I was thinking of nesting a for loop and creating a list containing all the students in each RegGroup. an obvious name for these lists is the RegGroup. The reason I want to do it this way is because teachers come and go and each year there will be a new set of reg teachers, Also the whole point of this script is to automate the process of setting up new students so having to hard code lists into the script seems redundant.

Any ideas on how I could achieve this? any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Apparently my question is too broad so in super basic terms

A) If i'm not supposed to dynamically generate lists with the values of stu['RegGroup'], then how can I go about achieving what I want (Lists with student details organised by stu['RegGroup']...Not even sure that is possible without dynamically generating them)

B) If it doesn't matter about performance and it is ok to dynamically generate list names like Nearoo said then how would I do this?

Comment: If dynamically creating objects is a concern to you, I'm not sure if Python is the right language. It's consciously designed in a way that you don't have to worry about such things. As a result, you barely have control over it. C is more the language for these sort of things. But unless it's really performance critical (_really_ critical, like huge simulations or real-time systems such as graphics cars), you shouldn't have to worry about this. Your task certainly isn't performance critical. So don't worry about it.

Comment: yes definitely not performance critical as it would run once a day, and unless its the beginning of the year isn't going to have many results to go through anyway. how would I go about doing this? I have heard about eval but have tried to avoid this because of the communities negativity towards it. I haven't read the docs on eval yet

Comment: So your dilemma is resolved then?

Comment: Unfortunately not as i'm unsure how I would go about doing this, see my edit above (pressed enter by mistake!)

Comment: So what are you asking exactly? How to send emails? You have to be more precise.

Comment: I'm sorry but I flagged the question as "to broad". Try to find out what precise step you're struggeling with, then come back and ask about that, and only that. Your problem might even solve itself if you do that! Just "how would I go about my program" is to broad, I'm afraid.

Comment: better? sorry I thought my question was pretty clear